# UWP:- How to add multiple row headers within a data grid?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid

I'm using the data grid control based on the information in this microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

How can we add multiple row headers within the data grid with a single scrollviewer for the entire grid w/o affecting virtualization?

[image]

I don't explicitly see an option, but is there a way to have it?

Comment: Hi, The `DataGrid` is based on `Column` rendering, and Column has only one `Header` property, which is not enough to support defining multiple headers across rows. You can try to splicing using multiple DataGrids.